# Reviewing `evalPair` from Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

evalPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a, b)
evalPair sa sb (a, b) = do
   a' <- sa a
   b' <- sb b
   return (a', b')
```

from [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch03.html).

I don't understand from where `(a, b)` comes, i.e. the third argument of `evalPair`.

Re-writing the function without the `Strategy` type alias:

```
*Main> :i Strategy
type Strategy a = a -> Eval a
        -- Defined in `Control.Parallel.Strategies'
```

it is:

```
evalPair' :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> Strategy (a, b)
evalPair' sa sb (a, b) = do
   a' <- sa a
   b' <- sb b
   return (a', b')
```

But, I still don't understand the `(a, b)` argument. Why doesn't `evalPair`s type signature show: `Strategy a -> Strategy b -> (a, b) -> Strategy b`?

Comment: You forgot to rewrite all occurrences of the `Strategy` type alias in `evalPair'`. That should give you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Strategy (a,b)` is a function of type `(a,b) -> Eval (a,b)`.

So another way of writing the signature for `evalPair'` is:

```
evalPair' :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> ( (a,b) -> Eval (a,b) )
```

Since function application associates to the right, we can remove that last pair of parens. And if we match up parameters we have:

```
evalPair' :: (a -> Eval a) -> (b -> Eval b) -> (a,b) -> Eval (a,b)
evalPair'      sa                sb            (a,b) = do
  ...
  return (a', b')
```

So that's where the pair `(a,b)` comes from.